# Image was cropped in the border when shrink it. How to fix that bug?

Tags: css, image

I have a circle image size 200px 200px. I shrunk that image to making a thumbnail size 40px 40px and it was cropped in the border. How do i shrink image but not cropped it use CSS?

[this is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyDfF.png)

this is my CSS of thumb box to get circle image from rectangle one.

```
.thumbBox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

this is my CSS of thumbnail:

```
img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a small code example of your problem in the question itself, otherwise we can only guess at possible causes.

Comment: Can you add snippet please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited data you provided the solution should be:

```
img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: i think it can't solve my problem. Because in a HD screen that problem is appear, in Full HD screen my thumbnail CSS work fine. Do you think screen resolution is the issue

Comment: I think your problem is that the image stretches outside of its container. It shouldn't be the resolution since you have set the fixed size on both the container and the image.